# Перебор элементов массивов специальным образом

Tags: c++

Нужно перебрать элементы 2 массивов таким образом:

1. Если элемент встречается только в одном массиве, то нужно записать его в третий массив.
2. Если элемент есть в двух массивах, то прибавляем к нему 1 и ищем опять, если же  находим - повторяем ПУНКТ 2. Если не находим - пишем в третий массив.

Например, для следующих значений ответ таков:

```
int arr1[] = {-2, 1, 2};
int arr2[] = {-3, -2,  0, 2};

int arr3[] = {-3, -1, 0, 1, 3};
```

Пытался решить проблему сам, но запутался в своей стратегии:

```
int find(int arr[], int size, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == number)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

int* buff_arr = new int[size1 + size2];
    int i = 0;

    int buff = (pkv_1[0] < pkv_2[0] ? pkv_1[0] : pkv_2[0]);


    if((find(pkv_1, sizeof(pkv_1)/sizeof(pkv_1[0]), buff) != -1) and (find(pkv_2, sizeof(pkv_2)/sizeof(pkv_2[0]), buff) != -1)) {
        if(find(pkv_1, sizeof(pkv_1)/sizeof(pkv_1[0]), buff) == find(pkv_2, sizeof(pkv_2)/sizeof(pkv_2[0]), buff)) {
            delete &pkv_1[find(pkv_1, sizeof(pkv_1)/sizeof(pkv_1[0]), buff)];
            delete &pkv_2[find(pkv_1, sizeof(pkv_1)/sizeof(pkv_1[0]), buff)];
        }

        buff += 1;
    }

    else {
        buff_arr[i] = buff;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас в примере все массивы упорядочены по возрастанию. А в условии ни слова об этом нет. Откуда взялась упорядоченность? Это дано?

Comment: @AnT надо, но если массив результатов будет неупорядоченным, то не проблема - всегда можно отсортировать

Comment: Вопрос в первую очередь про входные массивы. Если они упорядочены, то почему в условии про это ни слова?

Comment: @AnT, да, они упорядочены по возрастанию. Не посчитал - это важным: если даже записать массивы неупорядоченными, то можно их отсортировать.

Comment: Первая проблема, которая сразу бросается в глаза, это использование `delete`. Ему можно передавать только те указатели, которые были получены из `new`. То есть вы можете сделать `delete[] buff_arr;`, чтобы удалить массив `buff_arr` целиком. А отдельные элементы массива так удалить не получится, тем более что, `pkv_1` и `pkv_1` массивы даже не были созданы через `new`.

Comment: @february ничего не понятно, ну вот у вас -2 в одном и другом массиве. Если к ним прибавить 1у, то они снова будут одинаковые и так до бесконечности, но если инкрементировать только в одном массиве, то не понятно, почему в 3ем массиве нет -2. И что делать, если в одном массиве есть одинаковые числа(даже если сначала они были уникальными, то они могут перестать быть уникальными при инкременте)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat на самом деле `pkv_1 и pkv_2` были созданы через new, просто я не выложил свой код полностью, так как там очень много моих неудачных попыток, которые я закомментировал(а вдруг еще пригодится). Поэтому сюда выложил только часть кода

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon если --2 и -2 , то они сокращаются и вместо них образуется -1. Ищется еще одна -1, **если находится** , то -1 и -1 превращаются в 0, **если не находится**, то -1 помещается в третий массив. И так далее...

Comment: Не понятно где у вас цикл, в котором вы перебираете массивы, и чего вы хотели добиться `delete &pkv_1[find(pkv_1, sizeof(pkv_1)/sizeof(pkv_1[0]), buff)];` ? Удалить элемент из массива ? Это так  не работает, и если всё же вопрос по C++ то я бы порекомендовал вам использовать стандартную библиотеку

Comment: @february Нужно или не нужно их сортировать - зависит от алгоритма. А выбор алгоритма зависит от того, дано ли, что они отсортированы. Поэтому ни о каком "можно отсортировать" не может быть и речи. Давайте точное условие задачи.